# Jquery - split returned array(Json)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

ajax i have this snippet:

```
$("input#search_field").keyup(function(){
        var searchText = $("input#search_field").val()
        if(searchText.length > 1){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                data: {data: JSON.stringify(searchText)},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.result == 1) {
                        console.log(data.error);
                    }
                    if(data.result == 0) {
                        console.log(data.error)
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
});
```

When data.result is = 1, than the returned data.error is an array, in my console:

```
["string"]
```

My question is how get every string in my array into a different variable so i can use it later?

Because returned array could be also:

```
["string","string2","string3"]
```

Anyone knows?? Greetings!

Comment: Do you want to save the search values only for a given session (before the browser window is closed) or forever?

Comment: for a given session...until the event is fired again :) you know?

Comment: They are already in three separate locations. `data.result[0]`, `data.result[1]`, and `data.result[2]`. Why do you need to move it to separate variables if you can already access them as-is?

Comment: can i apply data.result[0] etc to html later?

Comment: and you know how to count elements in array?

Comment: cause i cant say : data.error.size...

Comment: @user3297073 you can use `.length` to get the number of elements in the array (e.g. `array.length`).

Answer (score 0):

I split the array as folow

```
var string = $('#uInput').val();
var array = string.split('\n');
for($i = 0; $i < array.length; $i++){
    var dateAndText = array[$i].split(',');
    $('#spota').append(dateAndText[0] + '<br>');
    $('#spotb').append(dateAndText[1] + '<br>');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't see how this is related to the question.